# How can I pass an class datatype as argument and use it for casting

Tags: java, generics, casting

How can I solve this issue:

```
private <T> void myFunction(float value, Class<T> classType){
  System.out.println("Value = + (classType) value);
}

Java Main(){
  myFunction(3.214, Float.class);
  myFunction(432.13, Integer.class);
}
```

I'm expecting the output:

```
3.214
432
```

But now instead, I got error. Cannot use `classType` for casting.

Comment: Why not just `(int)432.13`

Comment: @user7 Because I don't want to use an if-statement here. I just want to lear, if it's possible to do what I want to do. Thank you for the reply by the way!

Comment: It is unsafe to do a cast like this

Comment: @SiddharthKamaria So what do you recommend? Regular if-statement?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson It depends on what the use case is and how better you can design your code? For primitives `(int) 432.13` or `(float) 3.214` should work. With the approach you're going with, it can result in `ClassCastException`s if the client code is not careful with the class type.

Comment: @SiddharthKamaria Yes. I got that issue now. Could not cast Float to Integer.

Comment: Is your end goal to print as an integer or a real, or is that just for example? If the former, you can use `String.format()` with the desired format symbols. If the latter, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @AndyThomas I just want to learn if it's possible to use classes as arguments and use them as casting.

Comment: Yes, for reference types you can use `classType.cast( value )`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast an object reference to one of its ancestor types only.

For example, here your object is an instance of the [`Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) class. Its ancestors are the Number and the Object classes, and the interfaces `Serializable` and `Comparable`. Those are the only types you could cast into.

You cannot cast a reference to `Float` to a reference to `Integer` because `Integer` is not a parent of `Float`,

What you could do instead is pass in a function that converts floats to whatever type you want with whatever mechanism you want. The method declaration would look like:

```
private static <T> void myFunction(float value, Function<Float, T> function){
    System.out.println("Value = " + function.apply(value));
}
```

And you could use it like this for example:

```
myFunction(123.456f, Float::intValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [cast](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object))-Method of the Class-class.

Like this.

```java
private <T> void myFunction(float value, Class<T> classType){
    System.out.println("Value = " + classType.cast(value));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know it's a bad practise what he's trying to do. But his question was about his compiler complaining. With my approach it will compile but of course may fail at run-time.

Comment: Could not cast Float to Integer.